# Jquery each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given list

```
<ul>
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>sss</li>
    <li>ddd</li>
</ul>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $("ul li").each( function () {

          $("ul").empty();

          alert( $(this).text() );        

    });

});
```

This code returns every element normally, Why? Why list is not cleared at first iteration?

Comment: The .each() function creates a closure: that's what it's all about.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but try to use `console.log( $(this).text() );` so that you don't have to click the `alert()` away each time. On topic: If you don't need to do certain action on `<li>` items, just do `$("ul li").empty();`.

Comment: `var myList = []; $("ul li").each(function(){ myList[myList.length] = $(this).html(); }); $("ul li").empty(); console.log(myList);` with this code you will store the innerHTMLs for re-usage and still can empty them all. Might not be what you want, but I'm trying to show workarounds for your (possible) problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unordered list is indeed cleared in your first iteration, but the list items are still referenced by the jQuery object you created with `$("ul li")`.

They may not be part of the DOM anymore, but they still exist in memory, and you can still access and manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

The `.each()` function creates a closure: **that's what closures are all about.**

When the line `$("ul").empty();` executes, it clears the reference to the list but because the same list is ALSO referenced with `this`, the list is still there, just not referenced with `$("ul li")` anymore.

Comment: Closures capture locals, yes, but the `<li>` elements are still referenced in the jQuery object itself (that's how they can be bound to `this` in each iteration). `empty()` has removed these elements from the document, but they still exist in memory in a standalone form (i.e. their `parentNode` property is `null`).